# Azure Notification Hub Not Reflecting on Portal after Installation with .net Backend

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to register an app using **.NET Backend Installation** method. The method is executed successfully but the **Active Device Registered** is not getting updated on the azure portal.

But when I am executing **GetAllRegistrationsAsync** method, it is showing the new installed device. Can anyone help on this?

> Installation Method on the backend (C#)

```
public async Task CreateOrUpdateInstallation(DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation)
{
    Installation installation = new Installation();
    installation.InstallationId = deviceInstallation.InstallationId;
    installation.PushChannel = deviceInstallation.PushChannel;
    installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Gcm;
    await hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
}
```

> Get all Registrations Method

```
var allRegistrations = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);
```

> Active Device Registered on the Azure Portal

[image: Showing 0 on the Azure Portal]

Answer (score 0):

Normally Azure portal does not update "Active devices registered" on realtime basis rather it takes upto 24 hrs to show them. You may try after 24 hrs and you will get the devices if properly registered.